# Share code between web-app (Angular2) and mobile app (Ionic 2)

Tags: mobile, web-applications, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm new to these technologies so forgive me if some of my questions don't make sense!

I have to develop both a web app and a mobile app for my company. I was thinking about Ionic 2 since it uses Angular 2, and I would like to share code between the web-app I'll build with angular 2 and the mobile app with Ionic 2 since they'll do almost the same things.

How should I do that? I'd like to keep the logic of the application the same, and I would just modify something about the UI. 
Thank you!

Comment: I have replied at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499451/angular-2-and-ionic-for-web-and-mobile-app/45657874#45657874 See if anyone can find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll check out the article asap :) However, I noticed you used the word "Universal" which actually refers to Isomorphic, which is not the case and can be misleading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in luck.

With Ionic 2 (Angular 2) you can just simply take all the code from the `www` folder and place it on your web server and you're done.

Sure, you may tweak styling a bit, but then again it's not mandatory.

Truth be told, this can be done with Ionic 1 as well. However, it's not officially supported, but with Ionic 2 it is.

Comment: Oh, I'd have never thought it'd be so simple! Thank you ;) Do you use Ionic a lot? What do you think about it? I have to choose between Ionic and Xamarin, but since my apps won't require a lot of native operations, I thik I'll go with Ionic 2!

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit biased in this answer as I'm all-in with Ionic. I wrote a book about it, you can download it for free [here](https://leanpub.com/ionic-framework), wrote a 10k tutorial for [Pluralsight](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/front-end-javascript/ionic-framework-a-definitive-10-000-word-guide), and am currently [#3 top answerer]. (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic-framework/topusers) about Ionic framework here on StackOverflow. With all this said, I would still use Ionic over Xamarin as Ionic too has plugin support. Over 70 of them actually: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: In your opinion, is there something you cannot do with ionic?

Comment: 3D game would make no sense, for example, to make with Ionic

Comment: And for all other uses? I heard that ionic is slow when used with maps for example, can you confirm that?

Comment: Slow on which device?

You see, Ionic is as fast as an underlying webview on your mobile phone. 

I will answer your question similarly as I did on a conference talk I gave yesterday: just please stop with the analysis paralysis already. Pick a framework (any framework for that matter), use it and see how far it gets you. All these talks about X being slow or Y being better just make no sense until you try it yourself for your use case. 

People often cite Facebook as an example of them saying 'hybrid doesn't work'. True, it didn't work *for them*. The key word here is *for them*.

Comment: Do you have such a big user base and do you face the similar issues as they do? I doubt it.

All in all, mobile phones are getting faster. Thus, webview is getting faster. If you're building some business application where you have to get some data from some service, filter it and show it to the user and you don't have like 10k rows of data, you'll be just fine with Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is with NativeScript which truly allows you to share Angular 2 code between your iOS/Android app and your web app.

See the following bog post
http://angularjs.blogspot.bg/2016/03/code-reuse-in-angular-2-native-mobile.html

I was looking to use Ionic as well and was scratching my head for a bit with the same question but I do not think Ionic has true maintainable solution for this yet. NativeScript looks to be the first to have this as stated in this article, "This was impossible just a year ago, but now with NativeScript and Angular 2.0 this is a reality." https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/nativescript-2.0---the-best-way-to-build-cross-platform-native-mobile-apps

Answer (score 0):

I have replied to similar type of question at [Angular 2 And Ionic for Web and Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499451/angular-2-and-ionic-for-web-and-mobile-app/45657874#45657874)

See if you can find helpful.