# Angular 2 And Ionic for Web and Mobile App

Tags: angular, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

For my school project i have to build a web and a mobile app (doing mostly the same things). And i'm wondering how i should proceed to build them.

I'm going to use Ionic 2 for my mobile App and was thinking about Angular 2 for my Web App since ionic is based on angular i could use it.

I've read in another thread that i could just take the www folder of my ionic project and change the css for the web app.

My question is with which one to begin, create the mobile app first or the web app first ? Or use another solution who could be easier and save me some time re-coding the same things ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in a similar situation almost one year back and I created universal app (Mobile + Web) concept for common code sharing.

I have written a blog for the same at https://walkingtree.tech/index.php/getting-started-with-universal-web-mobile-application-in-angular-2

Now ionic is stable and it uses app-script for build process which I'm about to come through the blog where I have automated the build process for mobile and web.

Do let me know if you find it helpful. I will share latest Universal app code base repo with you.